# How can I check which Bachelor's degrees are offered by which institutions in Israel?

Tags: online-resource, bachelor, israel, pre-registration

I want to be able check, given the name of a field or discipline, which Israeli academic institutions offer a Bachelor's degree in that field or discipline. Hopefully also whether it's a B.A., B.Sc. or otherwise (LL.B., B.Ed. and so on).

I realize some of this information can be gleaned from just a search engine; and of course one could visit each and every university and college and check. But - is there some kind of central directory/website/list?

Comment: Interesting question. In the US, this is impossible (too many institutions, no centralized data base - source: son applying to colleges). Israel perhaps not so much. A further issue would be if the name of the field were uniquely defined - some things get messy like 'materials science' vs 'metallurgy' vs 'ceramics' vs ...

Comment: @JonCuster: In Israel there are 6 universities (+ 1 grad-only research institute), and a couple dozes academic colleges offering Bachelor's degrees, so its quite doable theoretically.

Comment: Israel is about the scale that a dedicated person could do it, plus or minus keeping up with (annual?) changes. Still, it could be hard to get one-to-one correspondence between all programs. If all the universities are under a government ministry they might have some data?

Comment: That is too bad. Kind of weird too, since you probably aren't the first person who would like to easily find all the options for a particular field.

Comment: @JonCuster: Found what I was looking for.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138236/how-can-i-check-which-bachelors-degrees-are-offered-by-which-institutions-in-is

Answer (score 3):

There is a [searchable database of degree programs](https://che.org.il/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%94%D7%94/#section-79454) at the website of the [Israeli Council for Higher Education](https://che.org.il/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%92%D7%91%D7%95%D7%94%D7%94/#section-79454) (which governs the accreditation/recognition of such programs and conducts periodic academic evaluations of them).

The search keys are a free string for the degree name, an optional geographic region, and an optional "level" of degree: "First", "Second" or "Third" (effectively - Bachelor's, Master's, Doctoral).

For example, a search for [First-level Math degree programs](https://che.org.il/%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93/?search=%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94&framework=%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F) yields 81 results; some are pure Math, others are Applied Math, and others are Math Education.

Caveat: The search mechanism is in Hebrew, as are the results.

[image]